# Polling USB card reader on background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java2

I want to poll card reader every second from android device.
Polling should be from background thread and result should be obtained on the main thread. I want to use RxJava for this. The polling thread should not die even if application goes in background.

Comment: What have your tried so far? Are there any examples that Google turns up, and how well do they match to your needs?

Comment: I have tried a looper thread with handler. I want to know the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have provided no details, I will make some guesses.

```
Observable.interval( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io() )
  .map( tick -> device.poll() )
  .filter( value -> goodValue( value ) )
  .observeOn( Schedulers.mainThread() )
  .subscribe( value -> updateGuiWithValue() );
```

This will perform the `poll()` once per second, filter to allow only `goodValue`s, and the move the value to the main thread where it can be displayed in your UI.

Comment: This works fine. I just have one more point that how to make sure this piece of code is always alive. I am using MVVM design so where to write this code.

Comment: If you invoke that code in a procedure from your main program it will continue to run until you exit the application.